# Could not find module ‘Data.Primitive.Ptr’

Tags: haskell, ghc

Does anyone have any idea why I'm not able to use Data.Primitive! I get this error whenever I try to import it:

```
Main.hs:8:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Primitive.Ptr’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
8 | import Data.Primitive.Ptr
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have the **primitive** module installed and even when I try to install it again (without --reinstall flag) I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
primitive-0.7.1.0
```

A couple of points to add:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- GHC version 8.6.5

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I install the packages using `cabal install primitive` and run the code using `ghc -c -O Main.hs`

P.S. I'm also pretty sure that I've run the same code on my machine but I can't remember if I had a different version of Ubuntu and/or GHC installed.

Comment: How are you running ghc and installing the packages? Please include details in your question.

Comment: @Aplet123 Just updated the post, thanks.

Comment: Can you also include the output of `readlink -f $(which ghc)` and `readlink -f $(which cabal)`? Also, did you install both from apt repos?

Comment: Yeah, I did install both from apt repos. And these are the results:
`/usr/bin/ghc-8.6.5`
`/usr/bin/cabal`

Answer (score 1):

Do `cabal install --lib primitive`. `--lib` is necessary for the libraries to be usable by GHCi and such.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Besides, `--lib` itself is not an option, at least not in the cabal version that I'm using!